# Background-clip issue on Chrome

Tags: css, background

I was checking the background-clip property on w3schools.com and I was playing with different values.

I noticed that on Chrome the background style updates only after window resize and I don't know if it depends by Chrome version (66.0.3359.181).

If you open [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-clip&preval=padding-box) and change values, do you see changes on background style?

I also tried with Edge and Firefox and it works perfectly.

Comment: Can confirm this still occurs on Chrome 70.0.3538.110.

Comment: @KoertvanKleef just tried it on 71.0.3578.98 and now it seems to work properly. Anyway thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems fixed in version 71.0.3578.98.